# Has Python's string formatter changes in recent editions broken the MySQL connector?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, string, formatting, mysql-python

I'm writing a simple - or it should be simple - script to acquire tweets from Twitter's API (I have developer/app keys and am using the Tweepy interface, not scraping or anything of that sort - I may ditch Tweepy for something closer to the modern API but that is almost certainly not what's causing this issue here).

I have a MySQL instance which I connect to and can query just fine, until it comes time to insert the tweet - which has a lot of special characters, almost inevitably. To be clear, I am using the official Python driver/connector for MySQL.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
```

Now, I'm aware StackOverflow is LITTERED with threads where people get my exact error - simply stating to check the MySQL syntax manual. These threads, which aren't all that old (and I'm not using the latest Python, I use 3.7.9 for compatibility with some NLP libraries) insist the answer is to place the string that has the special characters into an old-style format string WITHIN the cursor.execute method, to enclose string variable placeholders in quotes, and to pass a tuple with an empty second value if, as in my case, only one variable is to be inserted. This is also a solution posted as part of a bug report response on the MySQL website - and yet, I have no success.

Here's what I've got - following the directions on dozens of pages here and the official database website:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(twilek.search, q=keyword, tweet_mode='extended').items():
            twi_tweet = tweet.full_text
            print(twi_tweet)
            twi_tweet = twi_tweet.encode('utf8')
            requests_total+=1
            os.environ['TWITTER_REQUESTS'] = str(requests_total)
            requests_total = int(os.environ.get('TWITTER_REQUESTS'))
            # insert the archived tweet text into the database table
            sql = 'USE hate_tweets'
            ms_cur.execute(sql)
            twi_tweet = str(twi_tweet)
            insert_tweet = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', twi_tweet)
            ms_cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweets_lgbt (text) VALUES %s" % (insert_tweet,))
            cnx.commit()
            print(ms_cur.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

(twilek is my cursor object because I'm a dork)

**expected result**: string formatter passes MySQL a modified tweet string that it can process and add as a row to the tweets_lgbt table

**actual result**: insertion fails on a syntax error for any tweet

I've tried going so far as to use regex to strip everything but alphanumeric and spaces - same issue. I'm wondering if the new string format features of current Python versions have broken compatibility with this connector? I prefer to use the official driver but I'll switch to an ORM if I must. (I did try the newer features like F strings, and found they caused the same result.)

Comment: Did you mean to leave the quotation at the end after %(insert_tweet,) unclosed? I ask not to nitpick but because this syntax is just weird enough that I would believe that.

Comment: I'm legitimately confused: I thought the tuple was (insert_tweet,) with the comma making it a tuple. What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: What comes after `%` is just the arguments to the string formatter. An extra comma won't convert anything passed there to a tuple. If `insert_tweet` was already a tuple then it would have given you the expected result, but it is not.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are trying to use string formatting `c.execute(stmt % values)` instead of the preferred parameter substitution `c.execute(stmt, (values,))`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - I tried that first, I have literally tried every formatting schema for Python strings. This was just the last one I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should insert a row to your table,

```py
insert_tweet = "ABCEFg 9 XYZ"
"INSERT INTO tweets_lgbt (text) VALUES ('%s');"%(insert_tweet)
```

```sql
"INSERT INTO tweets_lgbt (text) VALUES ('ABCEFg 9 XYZ');"
```

#### Things to note

1. The arguments to a string formatter is just like the arguments to a
   function. So, you cannot add a comma at the end to convert a string
   to a tuple there.
2. If you are trying to insert multiple values at once, you can use [cursor.executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059091/3091398).

Comment: So,this is still not working - here's what I tried:

`for item in iterator:
    if 'text' in item:
        sql = 'USE hate_tweets'
        ms_cur.execute(sql)
        insert_tweet = item['text']
        sql = "INSERT INTO tweets_lgbt (text) VALUES ('%s');"%(insert_tweet)
        print(sql)
        ms_cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweets_lgbt (text) VALUES ('%s');"%(insert_tweet))
        print(item['text'])`

Comment: The response to get for that is the standard: `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'S HAPPENING!! Please sign the petition if you can! This could change so much for' at line 1` Obviously, it's still not handling apostrophes and other reserved characters well judging by where the Tweet starts in that error.

Answer (score 2):

I have these observations:

- the `VALUES` clause **requires** parentheses `VALUES (%s)`
- the quoting / escaping of values should be delegated to the cursor's `execute` method, by using unquoted placeholders in the SQL and passing the values as the second argument: `cursor.execute(sql, (tweet_text,))` or `cursor.executemany(sql, [(tweet_text1,), (tweet_text2,)])`
- once these steps are applied there's no need for encoding/stringifying/regex-ifying: assuming `twi_text` is a `str` and the database's charset/collation supports the full UTF-8 range (for example utf8mb4) then the insert should succeed.

  - in particular, encoding a `str` and then calling `str` on the result is to be avoided: you end up with `"b'my original string'"`

This modified version of the code in the question works for me:

```py
import mysql.connector

DDL1 = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tweets_lgbt"""
DDL2 = """\
CREATE TABLE tweets_lgbt (
    `text` VARCHAR (256))
"""

# From https://twitter.com/AlisonMitchell/status/1332567013701500928?s=20
insert_tweet = """\
Particularly pleased to see @SarahStylesAU
 quoted in this piece for the work she did


Thrive like a girl: Why women's cricket in Australia is setting the standard
"""

# Older connector releases don't support with... 
with mysql.connector.connect(database='test') as cnx:
    with cnx.cursor() as ms_cur:

        ms_cur.execute(DDL1)
        ms_cur.execute(DDL2)

        ms_cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweets_lgbt (`text`) VALUES (%s)",  (insert_tweet,))
        cnx.commit()
        print(ms_cur.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```